# Makefile: avoid code duplication using loops for defines and rules - is it possible?

Tags: makefile

I am facing a problem of making multiple targets, and want to avoid code duplication in Makefile.

I have many of these:

```
$(TARGET1): $(OFILES1)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OFILES1) -o $(TARGET1)
...
$(TARGET50): $(OFILES50)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OFILES50) -o $(TARGET50)
```

1) How to write it in loop, is it possible?

2) Will it work for defines? :

```
i=1 ; while [[ $$i -le $(MAX_TARGETS) ]] ; do \
    -include $(OFILES$(i):.o=.d); \
    ((i = i + 1)) ; \
done
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's nice that you have enough energy to worry about code duplication in makefiles.   I tend to focus on the source more, myself.  ;-)

Comment: The source is first, but this is also important :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with what you have:

```
$(TARGET1): $(OFILES1)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OFILES1) -o $(TARGET1)
$(TARGET2): $(OFILES2)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OFILES2) -o $(TARGET2)
...
$(TARGET50): $(OFILES50)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OFILES50) -o $(TARGET50)
```

Then use some automatic variables to reduce the redundancy:

```
$(TARGET1): $(OFILES1)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
$(TARGET2): $(OFILES2)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
...
$(TARGET50): $(OFILES50)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Then rearrange things a little:

```
$(TARGET1): $(OFILES1)
$(TARGET2): $(OFILES2)
...
$(TARGET50): $(OFILES50)
$(TARGET3) $(TARGET2) ... $(TARGET50):
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

At this point you *could* write a loop that would be equivalent to the first fifty lines, and another to generate the long list of targets in the final rule, but it's probably a good idea to look first at how you define these variables. Chances are there's a way to reduce all of this into a single pattern rule.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Beta.  Also, somewhere you must be defining all these make variables, anyway: why not just create the prerequisite lists then?  However, if you really wanted to do this you can use `$(eval ...)` like this:

```
define PREREQ
$(TARGET$I) : $(OFILES$I)
ALLTARGETS += $(TARGET$I)
endef

ALLTARGETS :=
INDEXES := $(shell seq 1 50)

$(foreach I,$(INDEXES),$(eval $(PREREQ)))

$(ALLTARGETS) :
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

The `eval` function can be tricky to understand, so I advise people to avoid it unless they *really* need it.